# Definite article "el" before infinitive verb

Tags: gramática

In a movie translated from English To Spanish (Le llaman Bodhi) the following was said by of the surfers in one scene:

*"No es trágico **el** morir haciendo lo que realmente amas"*

Is this the case when a masculine noun is omitted somehow (but article "el" preserved)?

Actually this sentence was written in subtitles. But in speech article "el" before "morir" was omitted (In English movies translated to Spanish, subtitles and speech always have discrepancies).

It is just that the only time I saw definite article before infinitive verb was "Al + inf", but then again there are no definite conclusions if "Al" in this case is very specific proposition or "A+el". Nevertheless, I understand the use of "Al + inf".

I am just wondering could there be also situations with "la + verb infinitive" and in which cases.

Comment: Short answer: always masculine.  Sometimes plural!  I found a page with a lot of nice examples: https://spanish.kwiziq.com/revision/grammar/using-infinitives-as-nouns-with-the-definite-article-el // This is a good question.  A suggestion going forward: the best questions are concise and focused. That makes them optimal for other Spanish learners to benefit from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The infinitive of verbs acts as a noun ([Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/el-infinitivo-1748/)), and can be preceded by the masculine definite article "el". However, in spoken language nowadays we almost always omit the definite article:

> *(El) hacer deporte es bueno para la salud (Doing sport is good for health).*

"Al + infinitive" is a different construction that means simultaneity ("when + -ing" or "on + -ing")

> *Se hizo una herida al hacer deporte (He got injured when he was doing sport).*

or cause ("due to + inf", or "as"):

> *Al ser menor de edad, no le permitieron entrar en la discoteca (Due to being a minor, he was not allowed to enter the club).*

Infinitives are always masculine, so the definite article, when used, is always "el".

Comment: Great answer, clear concise and to the point.. =)